# WP All Import: select a specific value separated by |

Tags: wordpress, xpath, import

Faced with the need to work with WP All Import. Everything works, but one of the fields contains data separated by `|`.

Something like this:

```
name:value|name1:value1|name2:value2
```

I only need to get `value2`.

I probably need to use the `xpath`. But I don't even know where to start)

If someone has encountered this, please share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the solution to my situation, maybe it will be useful to someone.

It turns out that WP All Import has an almost ready-made solution. All we need is a string to delete in regex.

```
[preg_replace("/.*?name2:/i", "", {params[1]})]
```

, where `{params[1]}` this is the name of the field in the import file.